# node.js log in with xhr post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, xmlhttprequest, passport.js

am using passport to handle the log in process in my app but, am not using a server side route which is a submitted from instead, am using an `xhr` post, but  because of that i got an issue that i couldn't determine.

here is the code of my app.js:

```
module.exports = function(db){

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

var config = require('./config/config')[env];

require('./config/express')(app);

require('./config/db');

var User = mongoose.model('User');
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done){
            User.findOne({userName:userName}).exec(function(err, user){
                if(user){
                    return done(null, user);
                    console.log('found the user');
                }else{
                    return done(null, false);
                    console.log('user not found');
                }
            })// query of findOne

    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    if(user){
        done(null, user._id);
    }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findOne({_id:id}).exec(function(err, user){
        if(user){
            return done(null, user);
        }else
            return done (null, false);
    })
})

require('./config/routes')(app);

    return app;
}
```

which is i don't get any of the log messages in my console, made me think i never query the database.

and here is the code of my route that i require at the end of the `app.js`

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
        var auth=passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user){
            if(err){return next(err);}
            if(!user){res.send({success: false})}
            req.logIn(user, function(err){
                if(err){return next(err); }
                res.send({success: true, user:user});
            })
        })
        auth(req, res, next);
    })
```

i handle the client side log in using `angular.js`  so here is the controller code :

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvLoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.signin = function(username, password){
        $http.post('/login', {username:username, password:password}).then(function(response){
            if(response.data.success){
                console.log('logged in');
            }else{
                console.log('failed to log in');
            }
        })
    }
})
```

the only message i got in my browser console is the one i logged in my `mvLoginCtr`l controller  "failed to log in" and i can't tell where my code fail and if it query the data base or not .but each attempted to log in with exist username i get the fail message any help or explanation is appreciated.

`express.js` located `./config/express.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(app){

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
    //app.set('views', config.rootPath + 'views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(favicon());
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'myapp mobile unicorns'}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
    //app.use(express.static(config.rootPath + 'public'));
 /*
    *Middleware to modifiy the header.
    */
    app.use(function(req,res,next){             
        res.set ('myapp-Powered-By' , 'mycompany');
        next();
    });
}
```

the log of the `response object` returned from the `post` request in the `mvLoginCtrl` controller

```
Object {data: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title>
<link re…/app/admin/mvPushCtrl.js"></script></body></html>", 
status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: 
Objectdata: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.min.css">
</head><body ng-app="app"><h1>userName is not defined</h1><h2></h2><pre>ReferenceError: userName is not defined?    
at Strategy._verify (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\app.js:21:36)?    
at Strategy.authenticate (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:90:12)?    
at attempt (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:337:16)?    
at authenticate (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:338:7)?    
at C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\config\routes.js:24:6?    
at callbacks (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)?    
at param (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)?    
at pass (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)?    
at Router._dispatch (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)?    
at Object.router (C:\Users\M-Mouallem\Desktop\mySpace\sandBox\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)</pre><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/toastr/toastr.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/app/main/mvMainCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/mvLoginCtrl.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/mvIdentity.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/common/mvNotifier.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/app/account/mvAuth.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/admin/mvPushCtrl.js"></script></body></html>
"headers: function (c){a||(a=vc(b));return c?a[I(c)]||null:a}status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object mvLoginCtrl.js:22
failed to log in
```

Comment: How do you initialize your app in `./config/express`? What does the `response` object contain (payload, status code)? Have you considered adding logging to find out exactly how far the execution goes?

Comment: i'll edit my answer and, post the code of my `.config/express` and i logged the `response object` i'll post it as well.

Comment: It says `ReferenceError: userName is not defined?` in the response HTML (which you probably even should not receive for ajax POST). Can't say much. Check where you have `userName` with capital N, and add `console.log` statements on the server side to find out how far you get.

Comment: I think it's already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289963/jquery-ajax-call-to-passportjs-login-on-express-nodejs-framework