# jQuery AJAX call to Passportjs login on Express (nodejs) Framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to use AJAX to call a login verification using Passport library on a Express application.
Im using local strategy like this:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {


  passport.authenticate('loginUsers', function(err, user, info) {

    if (err) {
       return next(err);
   }
    // if user is not found due to wrong username or password
    if (!user) {
      //return res.render('login', {});
      res.json({detail: info});
    }//(!user)
    //passport.js has a logIn user method

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {

      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.render('account', {});
    }); //req.logIn
  })(req, res, next); 
});
```

The problem is I dont know how to pass the variables to Passport, emulating bodyparser.json() functionality, im trying to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


   $('form').submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:'/login',
         data:  {username: $('#us').val(), password: $('#pass').val()},
         success:function(result){
            if(!result){
               //$('form input[name="username"]').css("background-color", "red");
            }

         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
         }
      });


      return false;
   });

});
```

EDIT-

My Strategy:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});


passport.use('loginUsers', new LocalStrategy(

  function(username, password, done) {
     users.findOne({email: username}, function(err, user) {

      if (err) { return done(err); }

      if (!user) {

        console.log('[+] DB: user/password failure'.red);
        return done(null, false, {error: ''});

      }else if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.hashed_password)){

        console.log(("[+] Password error").red);
        return done(null, false, {error: ''});

      }else if(user.verified === false){

            console.log("[+] DB: user not verified");
            return done(null, false, {error: ''});

      }else{

      console.log("[+] DB: user/password success".green);
      return done(null, user);
      }  //else
    }); //findOne
  }
));
```

Error on passing credentials persist, im geting:

Object {detail: Object}detail: Objectmessage: "Missing credentials"**proto**:

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work, untested, let me know if there's typos.

Basically, you need your express app to listen for a POST request on /login, in this route, you can add your passport auth.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('loginUsers', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.render('account'); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.json({detail: info});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Also, in your strategy, make sure the fields name are correct ie:

```
passport.use('loginUsers',new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'username',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
```

Comment: I've edited the original question, im doing that (post route) but I cant pass the variables to passport correctly. Thanks

Comment: what does your local strategy look like?

Comment: I'm not sure about passReqToCallback parameter.

Comment: you use it to to pass back the entire request to the callback if you want to display flash messages for example. If you don't need the req object, you can remove it

Comment: Is this line: data:  {username: $('#us').val(), password: $('#pass').val()},
valid?

Comment: yes, if you have the html elements with id 'us' and 'pass'. console.log your 'data' variable if you're unsure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62790/discussion-between-mdv-and-xshirase).

Comment: The error was on my html and ID's code, thanks XShirase for the help

Comment: I wonder if there's a similar middleware that is more suited for AJAX calls instead of relying on redirects...